# How to remove or add the border to the pdf content

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf, jspdf

I'm displaying the html content into PDF format. On clicking on a button the is saved as a pdf. For that i'm using the 'jsPDF' jquery plugin. Everything works fine. But the problem is, the contents are having border in pdf, like table format. I want to remove that border. As I'm new to this, I'm not able to find out where to add or remove the border for pdf content. Please help me in this issue...

Here is my html code

```html
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ITPortal.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/downloadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ITPortal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv-printshiv.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContentWide">
  <h2>WorkPlace Services</h2>
    <h3 class="curveBoxWide">Description</h3>
    <div class="curveBoxWide">
  <p></p></div>
  <table id="mytab1">
  <thead>
   <tr class="thead item">
    <th>Desktop Software</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>One time Price ($)</th>
    <th>Annual Price ($)</th>
    <th>One time Extended Cost ($)</th>
    <th>Annual Extended Cost ($)</th>
    <th>Sub-Total</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Symantec SEP</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">136</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Citrix</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">368</td>
    <td>85</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Oracle Database</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">270</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>PTC</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">180</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
    <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Windchill Heavy</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">0</td>
    <td>1600</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Windchill Light</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">0</td>
    <td>700</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Qlikview</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">915</td>
    <td>220</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Red-Hat Linux</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">0</td>
    <td>550</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Cisco Smartnet</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">0</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item category">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><p>Microsoft License</p></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Windows OS</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">125</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>MS Office</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">160</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Visio Standard</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">220</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Visio Pro</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">550</td>
    <td>110</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Project Pro</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">1050</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Project Server</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">4210</td>
    <td>850</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Project</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">125</td>
    <td>210</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>SQL CAL</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">160</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>SQL Server Standard</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">685</td>
    <td>154</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>SQL Server Enterprise</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">5210</td>
    <td>1470</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Visual Studio Premium w/ MSDN</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">4740</td>
    <td>940</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Visual Studio Pro w/ MSDN</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">800</td>
    <td>380</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>Sharepoint Server</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">3750</td>
    <td>850</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>Sharepoint sites Ent.</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">32000</td>
    <td>7100</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item category">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><p>SAP Licenses</p></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item">
    <td class="title"><p>SAP Bus Suite Pro User</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">2850</td>
    <td>570</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>  
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>SAP Bus Suite Ltd Pro User</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">1125</td>
    <td>225</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item odd">
    <td class="title"><p>SAP Bus Suite Expert</p></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" onfocus="if(this.value == '0') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="checkForm()" title="Number from 000 to 999 only allowed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" type="text"/></td>
    <td class="price">3750</td>
    <td>750</td>
    <td><input class="oneTimeExtendedCostTotal" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="annualExtendedCost" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
    <td><input class="subtotal1" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <td class="title"><p>Total:</p></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="grandTotal"><input id="total" type="text" value="0" readonly/></td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
 </table>
 <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
 <button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML()" type="button" id="buttonPDF">Save as PDF</button>
 <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="javascript:printDiv('mytab1')" />
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv(divID) {
            //Get the HTML of div
            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
            //Get the HTML of whole page
            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

            //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
            document.body.innerHTML = 
              "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
              divElements + "</body>";

            //Print Page
            window.print();

            //Restore orignal HTML
            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

          
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my css file

```css
.btn {
 border: none;
 font-family: inherit;
 color: inherit;
 background: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 25px 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 700;
 outline: none;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 200px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn-3 {
 background: #B9BBC0;
 color: #231F20;
}

.btn-3:hover {
 background: #f29e0d;
}

.btn-3:active {
 background: #f58500;
 top: 2px;
}

.btn-3:before {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 line-height: 3;
 font-size: 140%;
 width: 60px;
 background: #647685;
}

.btn-3d {
 /*padding: 25px 60px 25px 120px;
 border-radius: 10px;*/
}

.btn-3d:before {
 background: #677A8A;
 z-index: 2;
}

.btn-3d:active:before {
 color: #f58500;
}

#mainContentHome h1.title {
color: #C68332;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.clearBoth{
clear:both;
}

#mainContentHolderHome{
background-color:#002239;
min-height: 300px;
}

#mainContentHome a{
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
}


table#mytab1 {
border-collapse: collapse;
font-family: Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, san-serif;
background-color:#fff;
}

table#mytab1 th {
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 10px 8px;
font-size: 14px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

table#mytab1 td {
/*border: 1px solid #7eaac2;*/
border:0 none;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px 8px;
font-size: 12px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

table#mytab1 td.title {
font-size: 13px;
text-align:left;
color:#000;
width: 180px;
}

table#mytab1 tr.item {
background-color:#eee;
}

table#mytab1 tr.odd {
background-color:#DEDEDE;
}

table#mytab1 tr.thead {
border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
background-color: #666;
}

table#mytab1 a.button{
padding:5px;
background-color:#eee;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}

table#mytab1 tbody tr:hover{
background-color: #777;
}

table#mytab1 tbody tr:hover td.title{
color: #fff;
}

table#mytab1 tr.category {
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #ccc !important;
border-top: 2px solid #fff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

table#mytab1 tbody tr.category:hover{
background-color: #fff;
}

table#mytab1 tfoot tr{
background-color:#787878;
color:#fff;
}

table#mytab1 td p {
margin: 0;
}

table#mytab1 td input {
width: 50px;
text-align:right;
}

table#mytab1 td input.subtotal1 {
width: 100px;
}

table#mytab1 td input#total {
width: 100px;
}

table#mytab1 td.grandTotal{
text-align:right;
}

table#mytab1 tfoot td.title {
color:#fff;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
}

#sidebar1 ul.leftNav li a:hover {
color: #fff !important;
}

#sidebar1 ul.leftNav li, #sidebar1 ul.leftNav li a{
float:none;
}
```

This is the screen shot of my page: http://postimg.org/image/8zgnxtdd1/b4455e81/

Comment: Can you show us some piece of your code?

Comment: i edited my page.lease see on top...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your CSS code, but I assume that you haven't defined a border to your table. Use this on your HTML:

```
 <table id="mytab1" border="0">
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or in CSS:

```
 #mytab1 {
     border: 0;
 }
```

Comment: added that css. but no change. still i'm getting that border. i think whatever css we give in the external css file, will not taken to the pdf. am i right?

Comment: Maybe you need to share with us your CSS code, or share with us a generated PDF test. In this way, I can view what's the problem and attack directly

Comment: Im not able to upload page screen shot. Saying that 'nedd minimum 10 reputation'. Sorry...

Comment: You can upload the screenshot to an uploading page and share the link in a comment.

Comment: Please see the below link http://hicgwsdvapp01:44927/ITServiceCatalog/Documents/pdf-formar.png   are you able to see this

Comment: I am unable to access this host in this port (44927). I'm on working and this network is limited. You can upload to www.postimage.org ?

Comment: i added a new link: http://postimg.org/image/8zgnxtdd1/b4455e81/. Please see here

Comment: i gave [ table id="mytab1" style="border: 0 !important" ] but not working.I think the border is added using the jspdf file

Comment: No no, it is a CSS style. I talk to you about `border` HTML attribute. So the correct is in my answer: `<table id="mytab1" border="0">` . I tell you in the first code of my answer

Comment: I tried with <table id="mytab1" border="0"> this code too. But no changes. Even i tried in all the browser. Same problem...

Comment: So let me to research something in google, I don't know how it works.

Comment: the same problem with me.. please let me know the solution.